# Want to make the following rectangular box

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Want to make the following rectangular box in TeX. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Drawing office is closing early for May 1st feast ;)

Comment: Feast? its called the "International Workers' Day"

Comment: @SKKhan Please show us, what you have tried so far. If you have not written anything, you should start reading the manual of TikZ (just my recommendation). Or browse this sides for ideas. Or see http://www.texample.net/

Answer (score 5):

Another template. You can use rotated `ellipse` instead of `circle` for best visualisation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [tdplot_main_coords,
        grid/.style={very thin,gray},
        axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
        cube/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,fill=red}]

    %draw the axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,10,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z$};
    %draw the bottom of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,7,0) -- (3,7,0) -- (3,0,0) -- cycle;

    %draw the back-right of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,7,0) -- (0,7,2) -- (0,0,2) -- cycle;

    %draw the back-left of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) -- (3,0,2) -- (0,0,2) -- cycle;


    %draw the front-right of the cube
    \draw[cube,yellow] (3,0,0) -- (3,7,0) -- (3,7,2) -- (3,0,2) -- cycle;

    %draw the front-left of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,7,0) -- (3,7,0) -- (3,7,2) -- (0,7,2) -- cycle;

    %draw the top of the cube
    \draw[cube,blue] (0,0,2) -- (0,7,2) -- (3,7,2) -- (3,0,2) -- cycle;

    %draw dashed rect
    \draw[cube,dashed] (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,0,2) -- (1.5,7,2) -- (1.5,7,0) -- cycle;

    %draw circles
    \node[circle,draw,thick,minimum size=0.5cm] (fc) at (3,3.5,1) {};
    \node[circle,draw,thick,dashed,minimum size=0.5cm] (fcd) at (1.5,3.5,1) {};

    %draw circle lines
    \draw [thick] (fc.210)-- (fcd.210)--++(180:1) coordinate (A);
    \draw [thick] (fc.60)-- (fcd.60)--++(180:1) coordinate (B);
    \draw [thick] (B) to[bend right=60] (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using the Winedit 8 and MikTeX 2.9 but still this code not working "3dplot.sty not found"

Comment: Download it from http://www.heinjd.com/dev/latex/3dplot/3dplot.sty or `tikz-3dplot.sty` from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot

Answer (score 3):

Just for a template with PSTricks. Feel free to edit it as I set it as a wiki answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=30 -10 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,lightsrc=viewpoint](-2,-2)(8,6)
    \psSolid[object=cylindrecreux,h=2,r=1,fillcolor=cyan,ngrid=20 20,grid=false,RotY=90](0,2.5,1.5)
    \psSolid[object=prisme,action=draw,base=0 0 3 0 3 5 0 5,h=3]
    \axesIIID[labelsep=.5](0,5,0)(6,7,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]